# PHP: Не работает конструкция if else

Tags: php, sqlite3, search, if

Вот такой простой код для реализации поиска. Всё нормально работает, кроме одного: не выводит сообщение, при отсутствии в БД информации («По вашему запросу ничего не найдено»). В чём может быть проблема?

Вот моё поделие:

```
<?php

// Поиск статей
$search = $_GET['search'];

echo '
     <form method="GET">
          <input type="text" name="search" required="required" placeholder="Поиск" />
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Найти" />
     </form>
';

$db = new SQLite3(DB_NAME);

$search = trim($search);
$search = strip_tags($search);
$results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' OR content LIKE '%$search%'");
$numRows = count ($results);

if(empty($search)) {
     echo articles();
}
elseif(strlen($search) <= 3) {
     echo 'Слишком короткий термин (не менее 3 символов)';
}
elseif($numRows > 0) {
    while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {     
         echo 'По запросу ' . $search . ' найдено ' . $numRows . ' совпадений.<br />id: ' . $row['id'] . '<br /> Дата и время: ' . $row['datetime'] . '<br /> Заголовок: ' . $row['title'] . '<br /> Категория: ' . $row['category'] . '<br /> Контент: ' . $row['content'] . '<br />';
    }
}
else {
     echo 'По вашему запросу ничего не найдено';
}

$db->close();

?>
```

Comment: Надо проверить значение `$numRows`. Если оно 0, что скорее всего и происходит, понять - почему оно 0. Затем надо понять что применение метода `count()` к `$results` скорее всего бессмысленно и возвращает не то что вы ожидаете. Открыв мануал - можно увидеть что у SQLite-резалта есть метод, который вернет число полученных рядов. Но эт ведь думать нада, да?

Comment: И еще - если термин слишком короткий - то зачем выполнять запрос?

Comment: Так у sqlite3 разве есть?

Comment: Не пойму «если термин слишком короткий - то зачем выполнять запрос?»

Comment: «у SQLite-резалта есть метод, который вернет число полученных рядов» — ткните носом, пожалуйста.

Comment: Сорян, там число колонок. Но тем не менее - интерфейса `Countable` у резалта нет, поэтому вам всегда возвращается единица.

Comment: «Но тем не менее - интерфейса Countable у резалта нет, поэтому вам всегда возвращается единица.» А чего же тогда делать? :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/class.sqlite3result.php и читать комментарии.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что [$db->query(..) возвращает объект](http://php.net/manual/ru/sqlite3.query.php) , класса [SQLite3Result](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.sqlite3result.php) . А в php функция count корректно применяется для объектов, только имеющих интерфейс Countable (SQLite3Result не имплементирует этот интерфейс) . Заметка по count c php.net:

> Возвращает количество элементов в array_or_countable. Если параметр не
>   является массивом или объектом, реализующим интерфейс Countable, будет
>   возвращена 1

При анализе ошибок надо знать, что магии не бывает, и условный оператор не может не работать.